Shared Calendar for vehicle reservation in Sharepoint
I was tasked to create a vehicle reservation calendar for everyone in my organization, the Intranet of the organization is in Sharepoint and I am puzzled as to what would be the best approach to this task.
Do I use lists, or PowerApps or Automate? or all together?
Or maybe do it outside of Microsoft environment and just embed it after?
I tried with PowerApps but I have 0 knowledge about the syntax and its connectors.
Thank you for your time.

I guess you can use microsoft calendar and consider vehicles as rooms (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/room?view=graph-rest-1.0) so basically anyone can see if a room/vehicle is free or booked. You can even use microsoft bookings and create a booking page so people on your org can book online.
If you need a custom solution I recommend you using a third party tool like timetime.in or cronofy.
best,
